# Probability Strategy over many games - 5 chance to guess a number between 1 ... 100 (inclusive)

Tags: probability

Hi All Maths / Probability Strategists,

I play a guessing game over a number of plays.

**Rules:**

- You must make a bet (fake coins) when you play - between 1 and 240
- Objective to guess a number between 1 and 100 (inclusive)
- You get 5 guesses
- Response is... correct, higher or lower
- If you lose, you lose your bet
- If you win, you keep your bet and win the same amount
- If you get right the first time - your winning is x10s your bet.

You play multiple times over a long period.

**Obvious Strategy**

- First guess 50
- Then 25 (+/- based on lower higher)
- Then 12 (+/- based on lower higher)
- Then 6 (+/- based on lower higher)
- Then pick a random number between the last 2.

**Question**

- Is there a more efficient strategy over time?
- Aka. If my first guess was 25; and it said lower - I've massively increased my chance of winning; higher obviously a different story.
- Or perhaps 1/3 is better, aka. 33 is the best first guess.

**Feedback**

Would love to hear, what strategies people would employ.
Thanks

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have said it's a binary search. Which is obviously the optimal as base probability. However, it's not necessarily the best strategy over a long period of games, given the stakes.

Comment: If it's the best strategy for a single game, it's the best strategy over any period of time, unless the outcome somehow changes the rules, which I don't see.

Comment: You sure? Remember only 5 attempts.
Best probability isn't necessarily best long-term strategy.
Hopefully I don't get killed for that statement (:D)

Comment: Haha - just checked out your profile @saulspatz - you probably know better than I do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124229/discussion-between-saulspatz-and-mrdnk).

Comment: You dropped out of that chat, way too early

Comment: Let me put a proposition...
If my first guess is always 33; then 1/3 chance my bet will be less than 33.  If it's lower, then I am guaranteed to get it right, then I would follow binary search. If higher its harder but not impossible. Is the risk worth it?  Is final 1/6 every time, better than 1/3 where the 1 in 3 is guaranteed! I'm no maths genius but 1/3 sounds better odds than 1/6

Comment: You're right.  I've been thinking about this all wrong.  I've been thinking about minimizing the number of guesses to be certain you find the number which isn't the problem at all.  The problem is to maximize the probability of guessing the number in $5$ guesses.  What I said about the answer for one game being the correct strategy is true, however.

Comment: Fantastic! Glad you’ve realised the problem space. So what’s your first answer? FYI. I’m actually considering making this a fun Friday game for my team 

Comment: Wait, though.  There's a mistake in your calculations.  If you guess $33$ and it's lower, there are $32$ possibilities remaining, and you only have $4$ guesses left, so you aren't certain of finding the number.  Your chances are still about $\frac16$.  I'm not sure one can improve on binary search, but I have to think about it.

Comment: I'm not asserting that 33 is the best possible first guess. I really just picked it as a 1/3 to demonstrate the reality for the complexity. You are absolutely right on 33 being a 1/6 problem - if you follow with binary after that initial 33 - you come down to a 50/50. You have to ask yourself, is a 1/3 first pass; with a final 1/2 better then a last pass 1/6 - not an easy answer - unless you know!

Comment: But that's the ideal, what about random guess that are right, what's the effect of >33% then binary search.

Happy paths are great, and binary search is best when the game rules are find as soon as possible; but that's not the game we are playing here.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are $n$ numbers and we are allowed $k$ guesses.  If $n\leq2^k-1$, then binary search will certainly succeed, so we assume $n\geq2^k$.  I claim that no method can give a success probability greater than $$\frac{2^k-1}n$$

When $k=1$, this is certainly true, because we can do no better than guess a number uniformly at random.  Suppose that the statement is true for $k$.  We shall prove it is also true for $k+1$, establishing the theorem by induction.  Let us choose a number that divides the domain into sets of $m$ smaller numbers and $n-m-1$ larger numbers, and suppose first that $m\geq2^k,\ n-m-1\geq2^k$.  There are $3$ ways we can succeed:

- The number we chose could be the secret number (probability
  $\frac1n$).
- The number could be in the small domain (probability $\frac mn$) and we could guess it (probability $\frac{2^k-1}{m}$)
- The number could be in the large domain (probability $\frac{n-m-1}n$) and we could guess it (probability $\frac{2^k-1}{n-m-1}$)

This gives a total probability of $$\frac1n+\frac{2^k-1}n+\frac{2^k-1}n=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}n$$

Suppose instead that we choose a number so that one of the domains, say the small one has fewer than $2^k$ elements.  Then if the secret number lie in the small domain, we are certain to find it, and a computation like the one above shows that the probability of success is $$\frac1n+\frac mn+\frac{2^k-1}{m}\frac{m+2^k}n\leq\frac{2^{k+1}-1}n$$ since $m\leq2^k-1$.

So, how does binary search in the given problem compare to this optimum?  There are $15$ numbers we might choose as one of the first four guesses: $1$ possibility for the first, $2$ for the second, $3$ for the third, and $4$ for the fourth.  If none of these is the secret number, then the remaining $85$ intervals lie in $16$ intervals between the possible guesses, $11$ of length $5$ and $5$ of length $6$.  The probability of success in this case is $$\frac{55}{100}\frac15+\frac{30}{100}\frac16=\frac{16}{100}$$  Added to the probability that one of the guesses is the secret number, this gives $$\frac{31}{100},$$ the theoretical maximum.

**EDIT**

In an earlier version of this I had arrived at a probability of success of $\frac{30}{100}$ because I had miscounted the number of intervals of lengths $5$ and $6$.  But I've got it right now.  If $m$ is the number of intervals of length $5$, then $$5m+6(16-m)=85\implies m=11$$

Comment:  nice work so far

Answer (score 1):

Let's first consider pure strategies: strategies with no random element, where each guess can depend on nothing except the outcomes of previous guesses.

Any pure strategy with $5$ guesses has at most a $\frac{31}{100}$ chance of winning against a uniformly random number, because there can only be $31$ different numbers it can say:

- The first number must always be the same.
- The second number can depend only on the outcome of the first guess: higher or lower (because if it were correct, there's no point guessing anything else), so it can only have two values.
- The third number can depend only on the outcome of the first two guesses: (higher, higher) through (lower,lower). So it can only have four values.
- And so on. There are $2^k$ possible values the pure strategy can say after the first $k$ outcomes are known, for $1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 = 31$ numbers total.

Since no pure strategy can do better, no mixed strategy (that makes random decisions at some point) can do better, because a mixed strategy is equivalent to somehow randomly choosing between one of several pure strategies.

There are many strategies that achieve the bound of $\frac{31}{100}$. For example, we can pick any $31$ elements of $\{1,2,\dots,100\}$, assume the correct number is one of those elements, and perform binary search on them.